# Optimize 'if else' conditions in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am making an application, part of whose code requires many `if .. else` conditions:

```
   if @model_name == "Style"
        if row.include? ('colors')
          colors = row['colors'].split(';')
          model.style_colors.concat Color.where('code IN (?)', colors).map {|i| i.id.to_s }
          row.delete('colors')
        end

        if row.include? ('gender') and row.include? ('garments')
          @garments = row['garments']
          @gender = row['gender']


          row.delete('garments')
          row.delete('gender')
        end

        if row.include? ('sports')
          @sports = row['sports']

          row.delete('sports')
        end

        if row.include?('decoration_packages')
          @decorations_packages = row['decoration_packages']

          row.delete('decoration_packages')
        end

        model.attributes = row.to_hash.merge!(active: FALSE)
      else
        model.attributes = row.to_hash
      end
```

I need to make objects of `row` hash to access subclasses, and then delete them from `row` so it can be saved to a model.

Any idea how I can minimize the use of conditions or optimize it?

Comment: Don't use `and` as a replacement for `&&`. The former is for control flow, the latter is a boolean operator. (same for `or` vs. `||`)

Comment: What (class) is `row`?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are actually trying to do in terms of input and output?

Comment: Be careful about putting spaces before parentheses in method calls (i.e. `row.include? ('sports')`). The space completely changes the meaning of the opening parenthesis: `m(a, b)` is a method call, `m (a, b)` is a syntax error. Doesn't matter when there's only one argument but putting the space in is a bad habit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few optimisations here...

```
row.include? ('gender') and row.include? ('garments')
```

could be implemented as

```
['gender', 'garments'].all?{|x| row.include?(x)}
```

---

```
@garments = row['garments']
row.delete('garments')
```

could be implemented as

```
@garments = row.delete('garments')
```

---

You could actually squash a lot of these onto one line:

```
if row.include? ('sports')
  @sports = row['sports']
  row.delete('sports')
end
```

could be

```
@sports = row.delete('sports') if row.include? ('sports')
```

---

Also worth considering:

- Do you need to delete the values from 'row'? Could you just retrieve the value?
- What are you trying to do here? It looks like you're pulling a hash into instance variables... Which is what ActiveRecord does, basically. Could you just create a model with these attributes and then call it in this style?

  ```
  Style.new(row)
  ```

Comment: ActiveRecord does __not__ put attributes into instance variables.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes, it does. Particularly if those instance variables represent columns in the related table. However, if you add `attr_accessor :foo` to an AR class, you can initialise it with that attribute... `Kls.new(foo: 'bar')`

Comment: Given your line, I assert that `kls` will not have ivar `@foo` with value `'bar'` (if `foo` is a column, not attr_accessor) Checked in AR 5.1.5

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Interesting. I am a fair way behind, 3.2.22.5, but it's working here.

Comment: By adding attr_accessor with the same name as a column, you not only don't gain any new functionality, but you break the persistence of that column. In non-ancient AR anyway :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Ahh, I think I've expressed myself badly, there. I wasn't talking about an accessor for a column name, but for attributes which are not column names. Because it defines `foo=`, the new method will call that when presented with a hash.

Comment: But then you don't _need_ the activerecord? Just a plain ruby class with a couple of attr_accessor.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev That's why I was asking about the purpose of this code. It looks like it might be in a model, but I'm not sure. It's possible it should be. It's just not clear what the instance variables are on an instance of.

Comment: `@sports = row.delete('sports') if row.include? ('sports')` can still be optimized and just be `@sports = row.delete('sports')` instead. The documentation says *"Deletes the key-value pair and returns the value from hsh whose key is equal to key. If the key is not found, it returns nil."*.

Comment: An alternative for `['gender', 'garments'].all?{|x| row.include?(x)}` could be to save a key set at the start of the method, and use this for all multiple key comparisons. This would result in `row_keyset = row.keys.to_set` and change the comparison to `row_keyset >= Set['gender', 'garments']`. This is up for debate though, since it doesn't shorten it really, but if you check for multiple keys multiple times this might be faster since sets are optimize for this scenario, creating a set for just one scenario might not be worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

```
if @model_name == "Style"
  if row.include?('colors')
    model.style_colors.concat(
      Color.where(code: row.delete('colors').split(';')).pluck(:id).map(&:to_s)
    )
  end
  if row.include?('gender') and row.include?('garments')
    @garments = row.delete('garments')
    @gender = row.delete('gender')
  end
  if row.include?('sports')
    @sports = row.delete('sports')
  end
  if row.include?('decoration_packages')
    @decorations_packages = row.delete('decoration_packages')
  end
  model.attributes = row.to_hash.merge!(active: false)
else
  model.attributes = row.to_hash
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this with your current code:

```
if @model_name == "Style"
  row_key_set = row.keys.to_set

  if row.include? 'colors'
    colors = row['colors'].split(';')
    color_ids = Color.where(code: colors).pluck(:id)
    model.style_colors.concat(color_ids.map(&:to_s))
  end

  if row_key_set >= Set['gender', 'garments']
    @garments = row.delete('garments')
    @gender = row.delete('gender')
  end

  @sports = row.delete('sports')
  @decorations_packages = row.delete('decoration_packages')

  model.attributes = row.to_hash.merge(active: false)
else
  model.attributes = row.to_hash
end
```

- Instead of using `Color.where('code IN (?)', colors)` you can just use `Color.where(code: colors)`.
- Instead of using `.map {|i| i.id.to_s }` you can use [*pluck*](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck) (`.pluck(:id)`) to get an array of color ids. This also makes for a quicker query since only the ids get fetched from the database instead of the whole records.
- I personally like to use [sets](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) to check if multiple values are present in another set. For this reason I create the `row_key_set` variable `row.keys.to_set`. Now you can easily check certain keys are present on your hash by just checking if the key set is greater or equal than another set (thus being a superset). `row_key_set >= Set['gender', 'garments']` With just one check you could leave this out, but if you have multiple checks this might be worth the trouble. I also find code written this way also more readable, but that's just personal peference.
- You don't need to check if a key is present on a *Hash*, the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-delete) tells us the following:

  > Deletes the key-value pair and returns the value from *hsh* whose key is equal to *key*. If the key is not found, it returns *nil*.

  This means you can leave out the *include?* check and write the result from the *delete* directly to the instance variable. If the key is not present `nil` will be set for the instance variable.
- Lastly I would leave out the explanation mark in `row.to_hash.merge!(active: false)`. The version without explanation mark doesn't alter the original array and reduces the chance on accidental side effects. You're saving the variable to `model.attributes` anyway and toss away the generated array from the *to_hash* method. It's normally better to use non-altering versions of methods, unless you explicitly want a certain effect to happen.